# Place all empty values at last in array

Tags: javascript

I need to place all empty values at last in array. below code show what I try

1) This code sends all empty values at last in array but other values do not appear in a sorted manner.

```
var dateArray = [
  '','',
  new Date('2019-06-28',).toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, "."),
  '',
new Date('2019-06-01').toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, "."),
new Date('2019-06-02').toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, "."),
'',''
]
dateArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a ==='') - (b ==='') || a - b;
});

console.log(dateArray)
```

2) When i remove this `.toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, ".")` it work as expected but showing complete date in output `Fri Jun 28 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530` (India Standard Time). I only need to show this format `'2019.06.28'`

```
var dateArray = [
  '','',
  new Date('2019-06-28',),
  '',
new Date('2019-06-01'),
new Date('2019-06-02'),
'',''
]
dateArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a ==='') - (b ==='') || a - b;
});

console.log(dateArray)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last version works because

```
 new Date() - new Date()
```

will cast the dates to numbers (milliseconds since 1970) whereas:

```
  '2019-06-01' - '2019-06-01'
```

won't work as the strings can't be converted to numbers. Therefore `a - b` isn't tge right way to compare them. To compare strings, use `a.localeCompare(b)`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var dateArray = [
  '','',
  new Date('2019-06-28').toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, "."),
  '',
  new Date('2019-06-01').toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, "."),
  new Date('2019-06-02').toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, "."),
  '',''
]

dateArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a ==='') - (b ==='') || new Date(a) - new Date(b);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const formatDate = (t)=>  t.getFullYear() +"."+ (t.getMonth() + 1) + "." + (""+t.getDate()).padStart(2,'0') 

var dateArray = [
  '','',
  formatDate(new Date('2019-06-28',)),
  '',
formatDate(new Date('2019-06-01')),
formatDate(new Date('2019-06-02')),
'',''
]


dateArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a ==='') - (b ==='') ||  new Date(a) - new Date(b);
});

console.log(dateArray)
```